# CUDA: Using shared memory across different kernels

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

Is this possible?
I am trying to define a shared memory array in one kernel and then I need to use those values in a different kernel.

I tried declaring the

```
extern __shared__ float sharedMem[];
```

outside all functions and then wrote to it in one kernel and tried to access it in a different kernel. The `sharedMem` array is written to properly in the first kernel, but when I try to access it in the second kernel, the values are all 0. So I am guessing this won't work or I am doing something wrong.

Can someone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, shared memory does not persist across kernel calls. Instead you must use global memory (or texture memory) and load it into shared memory in each kernel call.